# Почему не работает connect из react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

https://toster.ru/q/515217?e=6351305#clarification_546115

Добрый день, выше это ссылка на вопрос с кодом, там в принципе всё описано.
Проблема следующая, я хочу создать контейнер - список проектов, в котором проект это отдельный изолированный проект со списком работ, для того чтобы данные в каждом проекте были разные, щас у меня, так как глобальное хранилище, если открыть список работ проекта и закрыть, а потом сделать это с другим работает хорошо, но если раскрыть два списка проекта то хранилище как и следовало ожидать обновляется во всех проектах.
Вопрос почему не может найти компонент Project ? Либо как это сделать по -другому на redux ?